# How can I scroll up more (increase the scroll buffer) in iTerm2?

Tags: iterm, iterm2

How can I scroll up more on iterm2 to get full output? At times, for example if I am doing unit tests, the errors are so large than I need to keep scrolling up to which I cannot scroll up anymore but the output continues further up beyond the top of the scroll. How can I access that? I tried page up more but not getting me there.

Comment: the similar question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459755/zsh-iterm2-increase-number-of-lines-history

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ZSH iterm2 increase number of lines history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459755/zsh-iterm2-increase-number-of-lines-history)

Answer (score 826, accepted):

There is an option “unlimited scrollback buffer” which you can find under `Preferences > Profiles > Terminal` or you can just pump up number of lines that you want to have in history in the same place.

Comment: the unlimited scrollback didn't work for me properly (maybe because of zsh or another config... I don't know) I had to put 100.000 in the textbox and unchecked the "unlimited scrollback buffer" option and now scrolling back is nicer

Comment: Why is that not the default?

Comment: Not easy to find, even if you use the Help search!

Comment: @ReduxDJ because that can quickly eat all your RAM, for example when logging the output of a webserver

Comment: Watchout for high memory usuage, when running a command with lots of output.

Comment: This should default to way higher.

Answer (score 72):

**Solution:** In order to increase your buffer history on iterm bash terminal you've got two options:

> Go to iterm -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal Tab -> Scrollback Buffer
>   (section)

**Option 1**. select the checkbox `Unlimited scrollback`

**Option 2**. type the selected `Scrollback lines` numbers you'd like your terminal buffer to cache (See image below)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## macOS default terminal (not iTerm2)

> macOS 10.15.7

1. open Terminal
2. click `Prefrences...`
3. select `Window` tab
4. just change `Scrollback` to `Limit number of rows to:` what your wanted.

### my screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know it's not iTerm2 but this is still useful - thanks for covering bases

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use [`less`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html).

```bash
$ command | less
a lot of output from the command
gets cut off and you're able to
read the top of the output first
and are able to navigate the output
...
```

If you're EDITOR is set to `vi` or `vim`, you can navigate using the standard navigation (<kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>). Press <kbd>Q</kbd> to stop reading the output.

Also, if you do decide to use the `Ulimited scrollback` setting, you can clear the Buffer using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.